# how can I save my plotly.js chart as a dynamic html web page?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly-python, plotly.js, export-to-html

I'm using plotly.js to create interactive plots and want to be able to export the plots as an html file, so the charts can be shared between users. I don't want these plots to be downloaded as static images (I already have that functionality), I am looking for the dynamic interaction.

I noticed that plotly python offers a built-in method fig.write_html() which does exactly what I want.

Is there something similar for plotly.js? I'm having trouble finding a solution.